# Define rvalue references to null

Tags: c++11, rvalue-reference

I am new in C++. I have a question like whether we could define a  rvalue references to null?

```
class Foo { }; 
Foo&& foo = nullptr;
```

I got the error:
**reference to type 'Foo' could not bind to an rvalue of type 'nullptr_t'**

Comment: Reference is a type that doesn't have null value. It's true for any kind of references - rvalues or lvalues. If you want to have null values - use pointers.

Comment: The real question is "why".

Answer (score 1):

> I have a question like whether we could define a rvalue references to null?

The standard (working draft) says that [no, it's not possible](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#5) (emphasis mine):

> **A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object or function**. [ Note: In particular, a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined program, because the only way to create such a reference would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by indirection through a null pointer, which causes undefined behavior.

It applies both to lvalue and rvalue references. See [this bullet](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#2) for more details:

> Except where explicitly noted, they are semantically equivalent and commonly referred to as references.